# Probability Someone Gets Pocket Aces in Texas Hold 'Em

Tags: probability

Nine players are playing Texas Hold’em using a standard deck of 52 cards (2-10, J, Q, K, A in each of 4 suits). Each player is dealt two cards. What is the probability that at least one player gets two Aces?

I tried the following approach, but someone told me I did the problem wrong:

I will call the players Player 1, Player 2, ...., Player 9.

P(Player 1 has two aces)

= P(the first card is an ace)*P(the second card is an ace | the first card is an ace)

= (4/52)*(3/51) = 1/221

Similarly, P(Player 2 has two aces) = P(Player 4 has two aces) = …… = P(Player 9 has two aces)

= 1/221

By the Inclusion Exclusion Formula, P(at least one of the nine players has two aces)

= P(Player 1 has two aces) +.. + P(Player 9 has two aces) - P(two different players each have two aces) (we have to subtract the last probability to avoid double counting)

P(Player 1 and Player 2 each have two aces)

= (4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(1/49)

Similarly, P(Player 1 and Player 3 each have two aces) = P(Player 1 and Player 5 each have two aces) = ……….. = P(Player 8 and Player 9 each have two aces)

= (4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(1/49)

There are 9C2 = 36 combinations of two players.

So, P(two different players have two aces)

= 36*(4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(1/49)

Putting everything together, P(at least one of the nine players has two aces)

= 9*(1/221) - 36*(4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)*(1/49)

= 0.0406

Can someone please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your solution agrees with mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated problem that takes very careful handling.  The primary difficulty with the problem is as follows:

Suppose that Person-1 does not have pocket Aces.  What is the probability that **then**, Person-2 does not have pocket Aces?  The difficulty is that the answer to the 2nd question, that of Person-2, **critically** depends on whether Person-1 was dealt $(0)$ Aces, or $(1)$ Ace.

So, under the assumption that none of the nine players have pocket Aces, you have to divide up the computations into $5$ mutually exclusive cases, that scrutinize that $k$ of the $(9)$ players were dealt a singleton Ace, where $k$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  So, I am going to handle the problem as follows:

The overall probability will be expressed as

$$\frac{N}{D},$$ where

$$D = \binom{52}{2} \times \binom{50}{2} \times \cdots \times \binom{36}{2} = \frac{(52)!}{[(34)!] \times 2^9}.$$

So, the problem has been reduced to computing $N$.  I will compute

$$N = N(0) + N(1) + N(2) + \cdots + N(4),$$

Where $N(k)$ is the enumeration, assuming that $k$ of the $9$ players were dealt a singleton Ace.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N(k)}$

Assume that there were $k$ Aces dealt.  There are $\binom{4}{k}$ ways of determining which of the $(4)$ Aces were distributed.  Now, without loss of generality, assume that the Aces were distributed in the order $Spade, Heart, Diamond, Club.$  This means that when (for example) $k = 2$, that the Spade and Heart were distributed, and when $k = 3$, then the Spade, Heart, and Diamond, were distributed.

Now, which ever suits are distributed, you can select the $k$ people who will receive an Ace in $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{k}~$ ways.  Then, when distributing the specific $k$ suits to the specific people, the $k$ suits can be ordered in $(k)!$ ways.

So, as a **starter enumeration** of $N(k)$, you have

$$\binom{4}{k} \times \binom{9}{k} \times (k!). \tag1 $$

Given the starter enumeration above, I will illustrate how to complete the computation of $N(k)$, with a specific example.  Then, I will expand this to a general formula for $N(k)$.

Suppose that $k=2$.  Given the starter expression in (1) above, you can assume, without loss of generality that:

- Player-1 was dealt the Ace of Spades.
- Player-2 was dealt the Ace of Hearts.
- None of the other seven players received an Ace.

Then, when $k = 2$, you recognize that there are now $(48)$ non-Aces left to distribute.

So, the **completion of** $N(2)$ is

$$\binom{48}{1} \times \binom{47}{1} \times \binom{46}{2} \times \cdots \times \binom{36}{2} \times \binom{34}{2}$$

$$= \frac{(48)!}{[(48-2)!]} \times \frac{(48 - 2)!}{[(48 - 18 + 2)!]} \times \frac{1}{2^{(9-2)}}$$

$$= \frac{(48)!}{[(30 + 2)!] \times 2^{(9 - 2)!}}.$$

The above expression generalizes to the **completetion of** $N(k)$ as

$$= \frac{(48)!}{[(30 + k)!] \times 2^{(9 - k)!}}.$$

Therefore, you have that

$$N(k) = \binom{4}{k} \times \binom{9}{k} \times (k!) \times \frac{(48)!}{[(30 + k)!] \times 2^{(9 - k)!}}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

The probability that none of the nine players has pocket Aces is

$$\frac{N}{D},$$

where

$$D = \frac{(52)!}{[(34)!] \times 2^9}$$

and $$N = \sum_{k=0}^4 N(k).$$

Finally,

$$N(k) = \binom{4}{k} \times \binom{9}{k} \times (k!) \times \frac{(48)!}{[(30 + k)!] \times 2^{(9 - k)!}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would be the answer to the question? What is the probability that at least one player receives Pocket Aces?

Comment: @mathteacher2022  The probability that at least one player receives pocket Aces is $~1~$ minus the probability that none of the players receive pocket Aces.  To compute the latter probability, you will need to apply a Calculator to the  formulas given at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it also possible to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Formula to do this problem? Before any cards are revealed, aren't the probabilities that any player has two aces the same?

Comment: @mathteacher2022 It is very plausible that Inclusion-Exclusion will also work.  However, while Inclusion-Exclusion generalizes better than the direct approach used in my answer, Inclusion-Exclusion critically violates an important fundamental.  When you are encountering a **new** problem, such as this problem (which was new to me), it is very important to forgo any attempt at sophistication or elegance, and keep things as simple as possible.  This is why I chose the approach that I did.  It was the approach that was the easiest for me to understand.

Comment: @mathteacher2022 Assuming that you are unable to find any flaw in my analysis, then, at a minimum, if you strive for a more elegant or more sophisticated approach, you can use my computations for **sanity checking**.  That is, if you use an alternative approach, and your final computations disagree with mine, and if my approach has no analytical error, then your approach must have an analytical error.

Comment: @mathteacher2022 There is something else.  Normally, in a problem like this, I would use a computer program (e.g. in C, Java, or Phython) to sanity check.  My PC will balk at attempting to loop thru more than $(10)^8$ situations.  The geometric mean of the numbers $\{52,51,\cdots,35\}$ is about $(40)$.  Then $$\frac{(40)^{(18)}}{2^9} \approx (10)^{(25)}.$$  However, if you were to explore various approaches, and had trouble resolving two different answers to two different approaches, then you could scale the problem down to $(4)$ players, instead of $(9)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, you could write a computer program to actually loop through each possible distribution of two cards to $(4)$ different players, and determine the exact values for the numerator and denominator.  Then, in the special case of $(4)$ players, you could compare the results of one approach versus another.  Whichever approach gives different results from the computer simulation must have an analytical error in it.

Comment: Using your approach, I got 0.0405910056. Using my approach, I got 0.0405910056. The answers are the same to ten decimal places (my calculator only goes to ten decimal places). I am still not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: @mathteacher2022 : "I am still not sure where I went wrong." : I am guessing that you are wondering why the original approach that you outlined in your posting yields the wrong answer.  The best way of attacking that is for you to apply the approach in your posting to the easier problems of $(k)$ players, where $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$  Then, apply an approach that you know is correct to the easier problems of $(k)$ players, with (again) $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then, examine the analysis of the two approaches, line by line for each of the four problems.

Comment: @ user2661923, my approach may not have yielded the wrong answer. My answer is the exact same as the answer using your approach. Assuming your answer is correct, my answer is correct as well. Can you see a flaw in my approach?

Comment: @mathteacher2022 Up until this point, I never scrutinized your posting, because your posting began with the strong suggestion that someone (presumably knowledgeable) had indicated that your approach was invalid/inaccurate.  Now, I just scrutinized your posting.  First of all, the fact that you apparently got (approximately) $(0.0406)$ using Inclusion-Exclusion and apparently got $(0.040591...)$ using my formulas, **in an of itself, is very suggestive**.  Further, I took a hard look at your analysis.  In my opinion, your analyis is perfectly valid and represents an accurate use of Incl-Excl.