# Probability That At Least One of Three Players Gets Two Aces When Each Player Is Dealt Cards

Tags: probability

Suppose that from a standard deck of 52 cards, three players are each dealt two cards. What is the probability that at least one player receives two Aces? How would I use the Inclusion-Exclusion Formula to answer this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The exact same methods used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550124/probability-someone-gets-pocket-aces-in-texas-hold-em/4550145#4550145) may also be used here.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

**For player 1:**

they get 0 ace, proba is $(48 \times 47)/(52 \times 51)$

they get 1 ace, proba is $(2 \times 4 \times 48)/(52 \times 51)$

they get 2 aces, proba is $(4 \times 3)/(52 \times 51)$

Sum is 1, good.

**If player 1 gets 0 ace, Proba for player 2 :**

they get 0 ace, proba is $(46 \times 45)/(50 \times 49)$

they get 1 ace, proba is $(2 \times 4 \times 46)/(50 \times 49)$

they get 2 aces, proba is $(4 \times 3)/(50 \times 49)$

**If player 1 gets 1 ace, Proba for player 2 :**

they get 0 ace, proba is $(47 \times 46)/(50 \times 49)$

they get 1 ace, proba is $(2 \times 3 \times 47)/(50 \times 49)$

they get 2 aces, proba is $(3 \times 2)/(50 \times 49)$

**If player 1 gets 0 ace and player2 gets 0 ace, Proba for player 3 :**

they get 0 ace, proba is $(44 \times 43)/(48 \times 47)$

they get 1 ace, proba is $(2 \times 4 \times 44)/(48 \times 47)$

they get 2 aces, proba is $(4 \times 3)/(48 \times 47)$

**If still 3 aces available, proba for player 3 :**

they get 2 aces, proba is $(3 \times 2)/(48 \times 47)$

**If still 2 aces available, proba for player 3 :**

they get 2 aces, proba is $(2 \times 1)/(48 \times 47)$

**Total :**
$(4 \times 3)/(52 \times 51)$
$+(48 \times 47)/(52 \times 51) \times (4 \times 3)/(50 \times 49) + (2 \times 4 \times 48)/(52 \times 51) \times (3 \times 2)/(50 \times 49)
+(48 \times 47)/(52 \times 51) \times (46 \times 45)/(50 \times 49) \times (4 \times 3)/(48 \times 47)$
$+((48 \times 47)/(52 \times 51) \times (2 \times 4 \times 46)/(50 \times 49)$
$    +  (2 \times 4 \times 48)/(52 \times 51) \times (47 \times 46)/(50 \times 49)) \times (3 \times 2)/(48 \times 47)$
$+(2 \times 4 \times 48)/(52 \times 51) \times (2 \times 3 \times 47)/(50 \times 49) \times (2 \times 1)/(48 \times 47)$

=1.356%

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I request that you edit your answer, using MathJax, as suggested by the comment of @C-RAM.  As is, your answer is hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

There is a systematic direct way to solve it.

Total possibilities are given by $\Large\binom{52}{2}\binom{50}{2}\binom{48}{2}$ which will form the denominator $D$

Denoting aces by A, and non-aces by B, there are only $4$ "good" patterns:

$AA|AA|BB: \;\Large\binom42\binom22\binom{48}2 \times\frac{3!}{2!}$

$AA|AB|AB:\;\Large\binom42\binom21\binom{48}1\binom11\binom{47}1\frac{3!}{2!}$

$AA|AB|BB:\;\Large\binom42\binom21\binom{48}1\binom{47}2\times 3!$

$AA|BB|BB:\;\Large\binom42\binom{48}{2}\binom{46}{2}\times\frac{3!}{2!}$

Adding  up the above will give the numerator $N$,

and the answer for the Pr = $\Large\frac{N}{D}$